# Localize Facebook OG Tags

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a webpage which uses Facebook `og tags`. The website is in German (de) and also in English (en).

I use the following og tags in my page header:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="34545345353453" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite.com">
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" name="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" name="og:title" content="${message(code:'page.title.home.index')}"/>
<meta property="og:description" name="og:description" content="${message(code:'page.meta.description')}"/>
```

The problem is that when I post http://www.mysite.com on facebook I get the preview only in English, even if the primary language is German.

How can I achieve that the translation is German if it is posted by someone who has facebook language German and English by someone how has Facebook Language English?

It is working for actions so it should also work if you use go tags.

Comment: Try `<html lang="<your_language_code>">`. e.g. for English, `<html lang="en">` It should work.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm struggling with the same thing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738381/supporting-multiple-locales-for-a-shared-page-in-facebook

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the 'locale' og pseudo?

Check this out:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/