# Supporting multiple locales for a shared page in facebook

Tags: facebook, localization, facebook-opengraph, meta

I'm attempting to have multiple title and descriptions for a same endpoint, one per language.

Trying to follow this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization#objects

I have a server that detects when the client is a bot, for example facebook bot, and it renders a single file with the title and description metas, and the following localization metas. I have a file for each language, and I set og:locale depending on the localization fb_locale that I recieve on the queryparams.

```
meta(property="og:locale" content="en_gb")
meta(property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_es")
meta(property="og:locale:alternate" content="it_it")
```

How can I have multiple language for the same endpoint?
This is my testing app and endpoint I'm trying to translate: https://webapp-server-21b.herokuapp.com/marcp

It seems that it crawls it properly, but does not display the preview in the language I expect when I share it on FB or in the debugger of facebook.

If I perform :

```
curl -X POST -F "id=https://webapp-server-21b.herokuapp.com/marcp" -F "scrape=true" -F "locale=en_gb" "https://graph.facebook.com" -s
```

or:

```
curl -X POST -F "id=https://webapp-server-21b.herokuapp.com/marcp" -F "scrape=true" -F "locale=es_es" "https://graph.facebook.com" -s
```

I get the expected title in the corresponding expected language, but when I share on facebook or in the debugger it's always in english, the default locale.

Thanks!

Comment: This only works for Open Graph stories, not for normal link posts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't entirely understand, could you give me more info? What is the thing that you say that only works for Open Graph stories?

PS: Open Graph stories are deprecated apparently.

Comment: The whole alternate locale thing is only supposed to work with OG stories. It has no influence on normal link posts - those always show the content the link returns, and don’t care about any alternative locales.

Comment: I have edited the post in order to make myself more clear, I'm explaining what I actually have, a server rendering a file depending on the language of the bot.

Comment: And I don’t know how I could possibly be any clearer: This. Does. Not. Work. For. Normal. Link. Posts.

Comment: Yes, I got that this won't work, but I'd like to know for the approach I could use that actually works